# Server Sent Events Stop Start with new parameter

Tags: php, javascript, server-sent-events

please help.

I'm using Server Sent Events to dynamically update a website based on data stored in a database.

I now wish to pass a new parameter ('abc.php/?lastID=xxx') back to the PHP script based on data received in the previous message.

I understand i can use `event.close` to stop the current 'stream' but im struggling to work out how to use the same `'EventListener'` for each new EventSource where the URL is dynamically created

Can somebody point me in the right direction please?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok spent some time pretty much getting better grip on Javascript.

```
var source = new EventSource("xyz.php?last=0");
source.addEventListener('message', onMessageHandler,false);

function onMessageHandler(event) {
   console.log(event.data);//just for debug purposes

   event.target.close(); //close current stream.
   var last = "1234"; // loaded from event.data in my solution.
   var sourceNew = new EventSource("xyz.php?last=" + last); // start another 
   sourceNew.addEventListener('message', onMessageHandler, false); //event

}
```

and i seem to have solved the problem i had.

Ta

Comment: Can you share the file inside ur PHP file?