# Server-side event - how to pass parameters to server-side script? Append query string?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to pass parameters to a PHP script that is used to stream server-side events.  I am using Javascript to listen to the events.  I have tried to pass parameters by appending a query string to the server-side script url:

Javascript:

```
var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php?file=query");
```

demo_sse.php:

```
<?php
  header("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n");
  echo 'data:'.$_GET["file"]."\n\n";
?>
```

I would expect to see "query" displayed, but instead I get no output.

I also tried:

```
echo 'data:'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']."\n\n";
```

But still no output.  I have verified that the script works otherwise (can print explicit strings).

I haven't found much on the subject, but I did find a couple of examples of appending the query string to the url in the EventSource argument: [Server Sent Events Stop Start with new parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685965/server-sent-events-stop-start-with-new-parameter).

Comment: What could you need to pass to the server? If you're looking for bidirectional communication, use WebSockets

Comment: @Ian: SSEs are sent over traditional HTTP. That means they do not require a special protocol or server implementation to get working. WebSockets on the other hand, require full-duplex connections and new Web Socket servers to handle the protocol. In addition, Server-Sent Events have a variety of features that WebSockets lack by design such as automatic reconnection, event IDs, and the ability to send arbitrary events. - quoted from http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/ - yes, I need to pass data to server to tell script where to find file.

Comment: @Ian: WebSockets are more complex, and require installing a module on the server.  I don't need continual bidi communication, I only want to send a single bit of data upon initiation of the server-side script.  WebSockets is overkill for what I need. The query string idea seemed like it ought to work, but I was looking for confirmation.  I hope someone can answer the question I asked.

Comment: why not just ajax a post request? is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 5):

I have tried the following code and SSE seemed to work:

```
var es = new EventSource('http://localhost/ssed.php?asdf=test111');
es.onmessage=function(e){console.log(e.data);}
```

ssed.php:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n");
echo 'data:'.$_GET['asdf']."\n\n";
```

How is your onmessage function written? Is it possible that your browser doesn't support SSE?