# HTML5: Re-start SSE after it has stopped?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to re-start the Server sent events after i have stopped it on a button click.

So I stop the event like so:

```
if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined") {
    //create an object, passing it the name and location of the server side script
    var eSource = new EventSource("mypage.php");
    //detect message receipt
    eSource.onmessage = function(event) {
        //write the received data to the page
        document.getElementById("serverData").innerHTML = event.data;

        if(event.data !=""){

        alert('success');

       ///Close it here///////////
        event.target.close();



        }

    };
}
else {
    document.getElementById("serverData").innerHTML="Whoops! Your browser doesn't receive server-sent events.";
}
```

**Now I need to restart the same SSE like so (if possible at all):**

```
$('#someBtn').click(function(){ 

//////this is actually my assumption and there is no such a function///
event.target.start();

});
```

Could someone please advise on this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can do what he is doing, check the below link.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13699370/4361743

Comment: @karman, i did look at that and tried to do what he's doing but couldn't figure it out! also, he seems to restart it immediately right after it has stopped in the same function..i'm not trying to do that otherwise i will keep it running.. I'm trying to stop it and then re-start it after button click.